# Linq Include property in every item of the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have these 4 classes.

They are being used in hierarchy:

```
  class Reception {
      virtual List<Pallets> Pallets { get; set; }
      float Weight { get; set; }
  }

  class Pallet {
      virtual List<PalletDetail> PalletDetail { get; set; }
  }

  class PalletDetail {
      virtual Package Package { get; set; }
      int Quantity { get; set; }
  }

  class Package {
      float Weight { get; set; }
  }
```

For each reception I want to calculate the weight, so I have something like this:

```
foreach (var reception in dbContext.Receptions
    .Include(a => a.Pallets)
    .Include(a => a.Pallets.Select(b => b.PalletDetail))
    .ToList())
{
    reception.Weight = reception.Pallets
                            .SelectMany(p => p.PalletDetail)
                            .Sum(r => r.Quantity * r.Package.Weight) ?? 0;
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that the object `Package` is not being included in the query, so the previous `foreach` is generating a SQL query in every iteration

Question: How can I include it? (what's the syntax?)

Comment: How? that's the question: "how can I include it?"

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730005/ef-7-how-to-load-related-entities-in-a-one-to-many-relationship - while EF version may be different, if you use Code-First, then it should be similar.. .and yep, what David said is probably OK too :)

Comment: `.Include(a => a.Pallets.Select(b => b.PalletDetail.Package))`

Comment: hmmm that's wrong... b.PalletDetail is a list ...

Comment: no difference, since to get .Package, it will auto-include PalletDetail and Pallets

Comment: Replace it, it needs to include the complete hierarchy anyway.

Comment: `hmmm that's wrong... b.PalletDetail is a list ` - so .Select again..  foo.Select(a => a.bar.Select(b => b.baz.Select(c => ....))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include the Package too, replace all of your includes with a single one:

```
var receptions = dbContext.Receptions
    .Include(r => r.Pallets
        .Select(p => p.PalletDetail
            .Select(pd => pd.Package)))
    .ToList());
```